# Include data in GAMS with an excel file

Tags: gams-math

I want to include my data in GAMS with an excel file

```
$onecho > Dateninput.txt
set=i rng=Sets!A2 rdim=1
set=o rng=Sets!D2 rdim=1
set=k rng=Sets!G2 rdim=1
set=n rng=Sets!J2 rdim=1
set=t rng=Sets!M2 rdim=1
par=p rng=Parameter!A2:D10 cdim=1 rdim=1
par=d rng=Parameter!G2:J5 rdim=1 cdim=1
par=l rng=Parameter!B33:O58 rdim=2 cdim=2
par=ti rng=Parameter!A18 rdim=1
par=M rng=Parameter!G26 dim=0
par=h rng=Parameter!G17:J21 rdim=1 cdim=1
par=cap rng=Parameter!A26:D29 rdim=1 cdim=1


$offecho
$call gdxxrw i=Daten.xlsx o=inputs.gdx @Dateninput.txt


$GDXIN inputs.gdx
$LOAD i, o, k, n, t, p, d, ti, l, M, h, cap,
$gdxin
.....

execute_unload 'ergebnisse.gdx';
```

The 'inputs.gdx' file shows all sets and parameter. My output file 'ergebnisse.gdx'just shows me the sets and one dimention parameter but not the two dimention parameter. Could you please help me what I did wrong?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Hard to say, w/o being able to reproduce this. My guess would be a problem in the gdxxrw call. Do the 2-dim symbols in inputs.gdx actually have the expected data? Or are they empty? It could help if you run gdxxrw with the option "trace=3" and post the log.

Comment: The  inputs.gdx have the expected data. And the trace doesn´t work.